# Cocoa get list and path of all the Login Items of the user

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

Is there a way to extract the list of all the Login Items of current User?

I have queried and found only Apple Script to get it, which is as:

```
'tell application "System Events" to get the name of every login item'
```

But I want this to do using Cocoa APIs, as running AppleScript in 10.14+ OS seeks user's privacy permission?

Comment: Traditionally, you would read the `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist` file. If you're getting permission restrictions on that, you might see if you can find what you're looking for from `launchctl`. But it's going to be a deep dive as `launchctl` is complicated to decipher.

Comment: Is your app going to be sandboxed?

Comment: @l'L'l: no it is not sandboxed

Comment: Have you checked `kLSSharedFileListSessionLoginItems`? and have you found any more effective solutions?